# Not understanding how Pandas styler works for exporting to excel (.format, .set_properties)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, xlsxwriter

I'm having some issues making Pandas Dataframe formatting work once exported to excel. I read https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html and tried to follow the examples, but the only ones I could get working are .apply and .applymap.

My code is below. I'd like to do three things - set the border color to black, set number to percent, and apply red to negative numbers using the Pandas Styler formatting functions, exporting that into an excel file. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter

np.random.seed(24)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.linspace(1, 10, 10)})
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10, 4), columns=list('BCDE'))],
               axis=1)
df.iloc[0, 2] = np.nan

def color_negative_red(val):
    color = 'red' if val < 0 else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' %color

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('example20.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(workbook.filename, engine = 'xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book

worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Sheet1')
writer.sheets['Sheet1'] = worksheet
worksheet.hide_gridlines(2)

df1 = df.style.set_properties(**{'border-color':'black'}) #this line of code doesn't work.
df2 = df1.style.format("{:.2%}").applymap(color_negative_red) #this line of code works only for the applymap(color_negative_red) section.
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

writer.save()
```